# Can any Grothendieck topos be presented by a singleton coverage?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, category-theory, topos-theory, grothendieck-topologies

If $\mathcal{E}$ is a Grothendieck topos, is it known whether one can always find a small site $(\mathbb{C}, \mathcal{J})$ with $\mathcal{E} \simeq \mathsf{Sh}(\mathbb{C}, \mathcal{J})$ and the topology $\mathcal{J}$ is generated by (or even contains) only singleton families, in the sense that $\mathcal{J}$ is generated by a pretopology or coverage consisting of just singleton families?

Comment: Maybe I am mistaken, but the Zariski/étale/fppf topology does not seem to be generated by a singleton - a presheaf is a sheaf if it satisfies the descent with respect to single cover maps, *plus the condition that the presheaf preserves finite products* (the later does not seem to be stressed in the literature). If you take the later into consideration, then you can consult the appendices of Lurie's [paper](https://www.math.ias.edu/~lurie/papers/Conceptual.pdf), in particular, C.6.4, which tells you that this precisely corresponds to coherent topoi.

Comment: Another way of saying that is that the presheaf satisfies descent for disjoint unions, i.e. the topology is generated by disjoint unions _in addition to_ the covering morphisms. Whether or not you can restrict to finite disjoint unions depends on the objects you allow in your site; if you only allow quasicompact schemes then finite disjoint unions suffice, but in general you must also allow infinite disjoint unions.